# How to pass the textview in listview back to php

Tags: java, php, android, listview

For this function, I need to pass the item mentioned in the custom listview from `Activity1.java` back to php in order to retrieve more information (including image via Picasso library) about that particular item in another activity from mysql, so may I know whether the php file is correct and how should I open `Activity2.java`.

**Activity1.java**

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String name =((TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemname)).getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Detail.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbConnect.php';
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
$NAME = $_POST['NAME'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_name = '$NAME'" ;
result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tem = $row;
        $json = json_encode($tem);  
    }
} else {
     echo "No Results Found.";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: There are may libraries that can do that aside from rolling your own. To name a few volley, okhttp...

Comment: If possible Picasso library?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Retrofit 2 library](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for making REST requests, which is exactly what you need.

First add following dependencies to your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {  
    // Retrofit & OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

    // JSON Converter
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

You will need to make an interface to describe your Retrofit service.
In your case it would look something like this (dont put / at the beginning of 
the path):

```
public interface PhpService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("path/to/your/web/resource")
    Call<Item> searchForItem(@Field("NAME") String itemName);
}
```

You need to make a class describing your item (you will have to write that class yourself, as I dont know actual fields):

```
class Item {
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("url")
    String imageUrl;
}
```

Now you need to create actual service like so (replace baseUrl with your website):

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://yourwebsite.com/")
.build();

PhpService service = retrofit.create(PhpService.class);
```

Now, using created service you can make a request to your php webserver:

```
Call<Item> item = service.searchForItem("yourItemName");

call.enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {  
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<Item> call, Response<Item> response) {
       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
           Itemitem = response.body();
           // todo do stuff with your item
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<Item> call, Throwable t) {
       // the network call was a failure
       // TODO: handle error
    }
});
```

That should be all to get item from your php script.

If you need more help check out this [tutorial by futurestud.io](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client).

Comment: about the baseURL is it the server name?

Comment: Its the address of a server on which you are hosting your php script. Could be domain like `https://www.google.com/` or it could be ip address like `http://172.217.20.174/`. If you are running script locally it would be `http://localhost/` or 'http://localgost:<port>/' if port you are using is not 80 or 443 for https